# Anexar arquivo .js dentro de outro .js

Tags: javascript, dom

É o seguinte:

Tenho uma página index.html onde o usuário seleciona uma determinada quantidade através de input radio.

Clicando em GERAR roda uma função onde através de document.write cria-se um formulário de acordo com o valor selecionado pelo usuário anteriormente. Ou seja, selecionou 2, aparece 2 formulários, etc...

O meu problema são nas máscaras desse formulário. (Data e RG)
Montei a página gerada através da função no HTML puro e as máscaras funcionam tranquilamente.

Basicamente é: Tenho um arquivo.js e quero chamar outro arquivo.js dentre dele. Já tentei o unescape, não sei se eu fiz uso errado da sintaxe, até porque está descontinuado, ou não funciona, sei lá...

Busquei em vários fóruns, encontrei basicamente a mesma resposta e nada funcionou até então. Como eu sou novo em javascript, devo estar fazendo algo errado ou deixando algum detalhe passar.

Espero que possam me ajudar.

---

Agradeço as respostas até então.

As respostas até agora não se parecem nada com o que fiz. T_T

Essa é a pagina index.html onde o usuário escolhe a quantidade.

```
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="content_body">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="img/logo.png">
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                QUANTAS CREDENCIAS VOCÊ GOSTARIA DE GERAR?
            </div>
            <div class="options">
            <form>
                <p><label> 1 </label><br>
                <input name="Opc" value="1" type="radio"/></p>
                <p><label> 2 </label><br>
                <input name="Opc" value="2" type="radio"/></p>
                <p><label> 3 </label><br>
                <input name="Opc" value="3" type="radio"/></p>
                <p><label> 4 </label><br>
                <input name="Opc" value="4" type="radio"/></p>
                <p><label> 5 </label><br>
                <input name="Opc" value="5" type="radio"/></p>
            </form>
            </div>
            <div class="submit">
                <input onclick="qtdd()" type="submit" value="GERAR"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Abaixo está a página que é criada ao clicar em "GERAR".

(Só coloquei o HTML, mas há a verificação de qual campo está checado)

```
            document.write(

            "<html>" +
                "<head>" +
                    "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text' href='css/credencial.css'/>" +
                    "<meta charset='UTF-8'/>" +
                    "<link rel='shortcut icon' href='img/logo.ico' type='image/x-icon'>" +
                    //Linkar javascript aqui
                "</head>" +

                "<body>" +
                    "<div class='body'>" +
                        "<div class='content_body'>" +
                            "<div class='logo'>" +
                                "<img src='img/logo.png'>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "<div class='title'>" +
                                    (1+i) +  "° CREDENCIAL - FRENTE " +
                                "</div>" +
                            "<div class='frente'>" +
                                "<form>" +
                                    "<p><label> NOME: </label></p>" +
                                    "<input autofocus type='text'>" +
                                    "<p><label> CARGO: </label>" +
                                    "<input type='text'></p>" +
                                    "<p><label> RECEBIDO POR: </label></p>" +
                                    "<input type='text'>" +
                            "</div>" +
                                "<div class='title'>" +
                                    (1+i) +  "° CREDENCIAL - VERSO " +
                                "</div>" +
                            "<div class='verso'>" +
                                "<p class='form2'><label> RG: </label><br>" +
                                "<input type='text' id='rg'> &nbsp </p>" +
                                "<p class='form2'><label> ESTADO CIVIL: </label><br>" +
                                "<select>" +
                                    "<option value=' ' title='Nenhum'> </option>" +
                                    "<option value='Solteiro(a)'> Solteiro(a) </option>" +
                                    "<option value='Casado(a)'> Casado(a) </option>" +
                                    "<option value='Divorciado(a)'> Divorciado </option>" +
                                    "<option value='Viúvo(a)'> Viuvo(a) </option>" +
                                "</select>" +
                                "<p class='form2'><label> DATA DE NASCIMENTO: </label><br>" +
                                "<input id='dtn' type='text'> &nbsp </p>" +
                                "<p class='form2'><label> ESTADO: </label><br>" +
                                "<select>" +
                                "<option value=' ' title='Nenhum'> </option>" +
                                "<option value='Acre' title='Acre'> AC </option>" +
                                "<option value='Alagoas' title='Alagoas'> AL </option>" +
                                "<option value='Amapá' title='Amapá'> AP </option>" +
                                "<option value='Amazonas' title='Amazonas'> AM </option>" +
                                "<option value='Bahia' title='Bahia'> BA </option>" +
                                "<option value='Ceará' title='Ceará'> CE </option>" +
                                "<option value='Distrito Federal' title='Distrito Federal'> DF </option>" +
                                "<option value='Espírito Santo' title='Espírito Santo'> ES </option>" +
                                "<option value='Goiás' title='Goiás'> GO </option>" +
                                "<option value='Maranhão' title='Maranhão'> MA </option>" +
                                "<option value='Mato Grosso' title='Mato Grosso'> MT </option>" +
                                "<option value='Mato Grosso do Sul' title='Mato Grosso do Sul'> MS </option>" +
                                "<option value='Minas Gerais' title='Minas Gerais'> MG </option>" +
                                "<option value='Pará' title='Pará'> PA </option>" +
                                "<option value='Paraíba' title='Paraíba'> PB </option>" +
                                "<option value='Paraná' title='Paraná'> PR </option>" +
                                "<option value='Pernambuco' title='Pernambuco'> PE </option>" +
                                "<option value='Piauí' title='Piauí'> PI </option>" +
                                "<option value='Rio de Janeiro' title='Rio de Janeiro'> RJ </option>" +
                                "<option value='Rio Grande do Norte' title='Rio Grande do Norte'> RN </option>" +
                                "<option value='Rio Grande do Sul' title='Rio Grande do Sul'> RS </option>" +
                                "<option value='Rondônia' title='Rondônia'> RO </option>" +
                                "<option value='Roraima' title='Roraima'> RR </option>" +
                                "<option value='Santa Catarina' title='Santa Catarina'> SC </option>" +
                                "<option value='São Paulo' title='São Paulo'> SP </option>" +
                                "<option value='Sergipe' title='Sergipe'> SE </option>" +
                                "<option value='Tocantins' title='Tocantins'> TO </option>" +
                            "</select> &nbsp </p>" +
                                "<p class='form2'><label> BATISMO: </label><br>" +
                                "<input type='text' id='batismo'> &nbsp </p>" +
                                "<p class='form2'><label> VALIDADE: </label><br>" +
                                "<input type='text' id='validade'> &nbsp </p>" +
                                "<div class='limpar'>" +
                                    "<input type='reset' value='LIMPAR'/>" +
                                "</div>" +
                            "</form>" +
                        "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                "</div>" +
            "</body>" +
        "</html>"
            )
        }
        document.write(
        "<div class='submit'>" +
            "<div class='btnsub'>"+
            "<input onclick='validacao()' type='submit' value='ENVIAR'/>" +
            "</div>" +
        "</div>" 
        )
        return
    }   
}
for(i=0; i<qtd.length; i++){
    if(qtd[i].checked == false){                              
        alert("VOCÊ PRECISA ESPECIFICAR A QUANTIDADE!")
        return
    }   
}
```

Eu até entendi o que vocês propuseram, mas acho que não é bem o que eu queria.

Ali em //Linkar javascript, gostaria de colocar isso:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/maskedinput-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/mascara.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Porém, com "todas" as opções e a minha capacidade esgotadas, não faço a minima ideia.

Tenho a impressão de que é algo bobo e simples, mas não consigo resolver.

Já tentei criar através de DOM, concatenar o "scr" + "ipt" e nada.

Tô aceitando dicas, críticas, sugestões.

Comment: Sem ver o seu código fica difícil de responder... Mas de todo modo, eu sugiro rever sua estratégia: por que não, por exemplo, colocar todo o JavaScript num arquivo só, e quando esse conteúdo novo for inserido no DOM (dica: prefira `el.appendChild` em vez de `document.write`) você atribui manualmente as referências pros *event listeners*? Uma opção ainda melhor - caso esteja usando jQuery - seria usar funções genéricas, que tratam de todos os elementos que satisfazem um certo filtro, **atuais ou futuros**. Isso é feito através de `$.on`. São só algumas sugestões.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um exemplo que talvez possa lhe ajudar.

Você pode ver o que o código faz nos comentários a seguir, mas basicamente ele gera um certo número de vezes os mesmos campos e aplica a máscara a eles ao final.

```js
    $('#generate').click(function() {
        
        //recupera radio selecionado
        var radio = $('input[name=qtd]:checked');
        if (radio.length == 0) {
            alert('Selecione a quantidade!');
            return;
        }
        
        //recupera valor do radio (quantidade de repetições)
        var count = parseInt(radio.val());
        
        //html com campos de cada seção do formulário
        var baseHtml = 
          '<div>Data <input name="data" class="campo-data" type="text"/></div>' +
          '<div>RG <input name="rg" class="campo-rg" type="text"/></div>';
        
        //laço para adicionar N vezes os campos
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            $('#myform').append('<div> Cliente ' + (i+1) + '</div>');
            $('#myform').append(baseHtml);
        }
        
        //aplica máscara de acordo com os estilos
        $(".campo-data").mask("99/99/9999");
        $(".campo-rg").mask("999.999.999-9");
        
        //inibe formulário inicial
        $('#gen-form').hide();
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="gen-form">
<div><input name="qtd" type="radio" value="1" /> 1 Cliente</div>
<div><input name="qtd" type="radio" value="2" /> 2 Clientes</div>
<div><input name="qtd" type="radio" value="3" /> 3 Clientes</div>
<button id="generate">Gerar Form</button>
<hr/>
</div>
<form id="myform">
</form>
```

#### [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/hu7nL0Lb/)

Answer (score 1):

@WiliamXavier, segue abaixo um exemplo.

Nele eu tenho um Modal que ao ser aberto é preenchido com um conteudo HTML gerado a partir de um template.

Apos ele ser anexado ao Modal eu inicializo o `input type="text"` com uma mascara, no caso `CPF`

mas para isto é necesario que o script já esteja carregado na propria pagina:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row switch small">
    <input id="Opc1" name="Opc" value="1" type="radio"/>
    <label for="Opc1"></label>
</div>
<div class="row switch small">
    <input id="Opc2" name="Opc" value="2" type="radio"/>
    <label for="Opc2"></label>
</div>
<div class="row switch small">
    <input id="Opc3" name="Opc" value="3" type="radio"/>
    <label for="Opc3"></label>    
</div>
<div class="row switch small">
    <input id="Opc4" name="Opc" value="4" type="radio"/>
    <label for="Opc4"></label>
</div>
<div class="row switch small">
    <input id="Opc5" name="Opc" value="5" type="radio"/>
    <label for="Opc5"></label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="btGerar" class="button small" type="submit" value="GERAR" data-reveal-id="modal"/>    
</div>

<div id="modal" class='reveal-modal' data-reveal=""></div>

<script id="tmplModal" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-2 column">
            <label for="txtRG" >RG</label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-10 column">
            <input id="txtRG" type="text" />            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-2 column">
            <label for="txtCPF" >CPF</label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-10 column">
            <input id="txtCPF" type="text" />            
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).foundation();

var btGerar = $("#btGerar");
var modal = $("#modal");
var tmplModal = $.templates("#tmplModal");

btGerar.click(function () {
    var content = $(tmplModal.render({}));
    var txtCPF = $("#txtCPF", content);

    modal.empty();    
    modal.append(content);   
    console.log(txtCPF);

    txtCPF.mask("999.999.999-99");
    return;
});
```

**CSS**

```
#modal label {
    float: rigth;
}

#modal label:after {
    content: ':'
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/59wtoL58/)

**BONUS - SCRIPT ONDEMAND**

Caso queira incluir o javaScript apenas no momento de incluir o HTML a pagina, faça o seguinte

```
$.getScript( "lib/jquery.js" ),
$.getScript( "lib/maskedinput-1.3.js" ),
$.getScript( "lib/mascara.js" ),
$.Deferred(function( deferred ){
    //carrege o seu HTML e inicialize os plugins aqui.
})
```